# Material UI Menu Using Routes doesn't scroll to the top on navigation change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am having a problem with scrolling, when navigating using Material UI's MenuItem Link component.

When I am navigating to a different component it is keeping the scroll position from the last navigation. However I want it to restore and start from the top whenever the navigation is changed.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function TopMenu() {
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar>
        <MenuItem component={Link} to='/'>
          <Typography >
            It doesn't scroll to the top when I navigate the the main page. 
          </Typography>
        </MenuItem>
      <Toolbar>
    <AppBar>
  );
}

export default TopMenu;
```

None of the below solutions have worked in my case:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}, [])
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where did you try putting those solutions? You need to put them in the component that each route is rendering

Comment: I wasn't putting them in the component that the routes were rendering. Thanks! Now, it works.